# How to get reference to map that is already set on div

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a div on my page called 'map', and I set google map in it:

```
(function () {
        window.onload = function () {
            var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng('@lng', '@lat');
            var options = { styles: styleArray,
                center: latlng,
                zoom: 15,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                mapTypeControl: false                
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, options);
...
```

Now I have some other functions and I need reference to this map div so I can add markers on it.
So how I can get reference to this dic with map to get map object?
I tried this way but it doesn't work:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempt does not work because that is creating a new `google.maps.Map` instance.

`map` needs to be declared a global variable. At least it needs to be declared a variable outside of the function which reference you assign to `window.onload`. JavaScript 101.